# How to type 'password' as asterisks in Slack application?

Tags: bots, slack, slack-api, password-encryption

I need to pass 'Keyword', 'Username' and 'Password' in Slack App in order to trigger a bot that does something (e.g. get all job names from Jenkins and the credentials are the user's on Jenkins server). How can the password be shown on the Slack app screen as asterisks and not as clear text?

I have searched the web and found browser extensions for Slack etc.
I do not need a solution for browsers, but only for the app in Mac, Windows, iPhone etc.

when "get something" is the keyword to trigger the bot, then typing username (foo) and password (bar), the actual typing would be:

"get something foo bar"

but the expected characters on screen should be:

"get something foo ***"

I would consider even changing the architecture a bit.

Answer (score 1):

There is no special support for password input in the Slack API.

But to ensure that the password is only visible to the user that enters it you can open a [`modal`](https://api.slack.com/surfaces/modals) that asks the user for the password. Modals are modal dialog windows that only appear the user that initiated the action.

In full context you could do the following:

1. User calls your app with a [slash command](https://api.slack.com/interactivity/slash-commands), e.g. `/myapp keyword username`
2. Modal opens to the user asking for the password

Alternatively you can just use a slash command, since its input is not shown to the rest of the channel, e.g. `/myapp keyword username password`.

Comment: It's not quite what I need, because the password is still written as clear text and is visible to anyone who can look at the screen. But thanks anyway :)

Comment: I know, but that is the best you can do with Slack.